# Where to get OpenAL in form of static build?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, openal

Where to get OpenAL in form of static (.lib) build? (my point is to compile my app into 1 file with all needed inside)

Answer (score -1):

Go here:

http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/Downloads/Forms/AllItems.aspx

And download: "OpenAL Installer for Windows"

Comment: This answer is useless, it's basically "How do I make a cake?" and you answer "Go ride this bicycle".